# Android xml layout blank space

Tags: android, xml, layout

Iam developing a HTML5 Android app, and Iam stucked at basic xml layout of Android app. When I run my app in emulator and on my Android smartphone I have unexpected blank space on the right side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3emH.png

Here is code form activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
              android:orientation="vertical"  
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        >  
    <WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"  
             android:layout_width="match_parent"  
             android:layout_height="match_parent"  
            />  
</LinearLayout>
```